# Session created by one project is also accessible by other project in PHP

Tags: php, session

In one of my project on localhost a session is created for user login. It is stored in `$_SESSION['uname']`. My some other project is also using the same session name variable. The problem is when I already have logged into my first project admin area and then I go to my other project admin area, it doesn't ask me to enter credentials to login window; instead it directly takes me to the admin panel. I know this is happening due to the use of same `$_SESSION['uname']` in my various projects. So I am wondering how we can force other project to display log in window although I have already logged into my first project?

It might also possible that my other project has some different login credentials but I will never offer me login screen if I have already logged into my first project.

I am also thinking that how the professional websites keep their session name unique so that other can never use it? In my case the session name is accessible everywhere.

Comment: What was the real need of answering my question so soon if you first didn't read it carefully? I already wrote its due to using same session variable name. I knew it already.

Comment: Great wait for sometime. You will get good things comes for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using localhost for every projects in your local.

1. Create separate VirtualHost for each project, then session will be unique for each project - as the cookie's domains are different.
2. If you want to keep localhost (I'd not recommend), you should think about namespace for session of each project, like $_SESSION['project1']['uname']

Answer (score 0):

You can use `session_unset()` in logout screen then `$_SESSION['uname']` will be null

Otherwise use special names for the uname (maybe ['uname'][0])

You can also use md5 for uname `$_SESSION[md5("project 1 uname")];`
or `$_SESSION[md5("project 1 namespace")]["uname"];`

Hope I helped.

Comment: No, not a satisfactory answer to me. I already told if I have already logged into my project-1 and goes to project-2 login. It will directly take to me the admin panel. Since I didn't logged out of my project-1. How the professional website ensures their session name will always be unique and will never be used by some other site?

Comment: They are using random strings and not putting two sites on the same server

Comment: Best way? `$_SESSION[md5("project 1 uname")];`

Answer (score 0):

It's mainly because you are using localhost or same host for all your projects.Try setting a virtual host for your project.

Refer the link for setting virtual host

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

Check the php.ini [session.cookie_domain](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain) directive, to specify the domain set in session cookie.

Or you may check the [`session_set_cookie_params`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) function. It has `$domain` parameter to set the domain where the session cookie is accessible.

For example to set the session cookie only visible to `mywebsite.com`:

```
<?php

session_set_cookie_params(3600, '/', 'mywebsite.com');

session_start();
```